# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound 6

Tags: php, pdo

```
<?php

....

require 'connect.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subject WHERE subId=:id";
    $getrows = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $getrows->execute();
    $rows = $getrows->fetchAll();
    foreach($rows as $row){


?>
```

Comment: Look this : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php 
You should bind your param "id" in your query, use PDO or just : SELECT * FROM subject WHERE subId=" . $id

Comment: You have a placeholder (`:id`) in your query, but you never pass any value to it. Just do: `$getrows->execute([':id' => $id]);` (replace `$id` with your real variable/value).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you need to use `bindParam()` method:

```
$id = 1;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM subject WHERE subId=:subId";
$sql = bindParam(':subId', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT)
$getrows = $conn->prepare($sql);
$getrows->execute();
$rows = $getrows->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $row){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind param in execute method like that:

```
$getrows->execute([':subId' => $myid])
```